# SVG content - only scale width and show full height

Tags: html, css, svg

I have created an SVG with foreignObject text and linked it in my HTML page using the img tag.

The issue is that the width of the svg is scaled as per device but the height is fixed around 153px. I have set the svg width and height to 100%.

I cannot provide fixed height for svg because I want the text part to be responsive and scale as per device.

So the foreignObject text content gets cut off as the image doesn't show the height in full.

I have tried the viewBox and preserveAspectRatio unsuccessfully.

here is the Jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/yftwn5np/)

```
<img src="http://treebliss.com/shipping.svg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"/>
```

screenshot from actual use [image: screenshot]

I cannot use any JS for any solution in this situation.

Comment: I think you missed adding this css in your file html, body{width:100%; height:100%;}. Adding this would solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Viewport-percentage lengths:**

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly. However,
>   when the value of overflow on the root element is auto, any scroll
>   bars are assumed not to exist.  As an alternative to setting both the
>   html/body element's heights to 100%, you could also use
>   viewport-percentage lengths:

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
img {
  width: 100%; 
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://treebliss.com/shipping.svg"  />
```

Comment: Similar issues to the other answer: The div height is too long and if it is surrounded by other elements layout cannot be maintained. In small viewport the height is too little for the svg and it appears cut off again.

Answer (score 0):

The image should be in a container with 100% height (vh)

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yftwn5np/6/)

```
div {
text-align: center;
height: 100vh;
}
img {
border: thin dotted darkgrey;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Two issues: The div height is too long and if it is surrounded by other elements layout cannot be maintained. In small viewport the height is too little for the svg and it appears cut off again.

Comment: That depends on the rest of your layout... But the answers are correct for your question.

Comment: Actually my question did mention that the text part be responsive. The viewport solution doesn't work if you resize the browser or when text is longer than the height. Thank you anyway, I will keep looking into this.